# reactjs deployed on Azure-Static-web can't download blob

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-static-web-app

I have a Static web app in Azure. It's written with Reactjs and I want to download the response of calling an API.

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch('URL', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ${token}',
        Accept: 'text/csv',
      },
    })
      .then((res) => (res.ok ? res.blob() : Promise.reject(new Error('File not found'))))
      .then((blob) => {
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([blob]));

        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = url;
        link.setAttribute('download', 'filename.csv');
        console.log('data received from backend', blob);
        link.click();
        resolve();
      })
      .catch(({ message }) => reject(message));
  });
```

It's working on my local system but I have a problem when it's deployed on a Azure Static web app.

When I trigger the download file button the CSV file contains the HTML code below.

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <base href=""/>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.png"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width   initial-scale=1"/>
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/>
        <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app"/>
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="logo192.png"/>
        <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json"/>
        <title>My website</title>
        <link href="/static/css/2.a86954d2.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="/static/css/main.58874b1d.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
            <body>
                <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
                <div id="root"/>
                <script>!function(e){function r(r){for(var n    a   l=r[0]  i=r[1]  p=r[2]  c=0 s=[];c<l.length;c++)a=l[c] Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o a)&&o[a]&&s.push(o[a][0]) o[a]=0;
                for(n in i)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(i n)&&(e[n]=i[n]);for(f&&f(r);s.length;)s.shift()();return u.push.apply(u p||[]) t()}
                function t(){for(var e r=0;r<u.length;r++){for(var t=u[r] n=!0 l=1;l<t.length;l++){var i=t[l];0!==o[i]&&(n=!1)}n&&(u.splice(r-- 1) e=a(a.s=t[0]))}return e}var n={} o={1:0} u=[];function a(r){if(n[r])return n[r].exports;var t=n[r]={i:r l:!1 exports:{}};
                return e[r].call(t.exports t t.exports a) t.l=!0 t.exports}a.m=e a.c=n a.d=function(e r t){a.o(e r)||Object.defineProperty(e r {enumerable:!0 get:t})}
                a.r=function(e){"undefined" !=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e Symbol.toStringTag {value:"Module"})
                Object.defineProperty(e __esModule {value:!0})} a.t=function(e r){if(1&r&&(e=a(e)) 8&r)return e;if(4&r&&"object"==typeof e&&e&&e.__esModule)return e;
                var t=Object.create(null);if(a.r(t) Object.defineProperty(t default {enumerable:!0 value:e}) 2&r&&"string"!=typeof e)for(var n in e)a.d(t n function(r){return e[r]}.bind(null n));
                return t} a.n=function(e){var r=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return a.d(r a r) r} a.o=function(e r){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e r)} 
                a.p="/" ;var l=this["webpackJsonphandbook-admin-panel" ]=this["webpackJsonphandbook-admin-panel" ]||[] i=l.push.bind(l);l.push=r l=l.slice();for(var p=0;p<l.length;p++)r(l[p]);var f=i;t()}([])
                </script><script src="/static/js/2.cacac8cc.chunk.js"/>
                    <script src="/static/js/main.bbc25d92.chunk.js"/>
                </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include any error messages that you are getting.

Comment: @GauravMantri, I updated the question. this is what the CSV file contains.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of different changes in react code, I found the problem was with the URL of the backend code.
I checked the networking tab in the browser and added some logs to check the response of the backend.
It was a relative URL, and in my local system, it was using the proxy to connect to the backend. I added the backend BaseURL, and it is working now.